# Android Microsoft Translator API- error getting languages supported to translate text

Tags: android

I am trying to get a list of languages supported to translate text by using `Microsoft Translator API`.

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-Java/blob/master/Languages.java) but I get this error on line 49:

```
    `Method threw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' exception.`
```

When I change this method:

`connection.getInputStream();`

by

`connection.getErrorStream();`

I get this error: `{"code":405000,"message":"The request method is not supported for the requested resource."}`

Does anyone know where is the problem??

Thanks in advance!